Dummy Output and No Input devices on 2017 iMac Pro
I am new to Linux and am trying to start using Linux on my 2017 iMac Pro that has an Intel Xeon W chip. I was able to successfully install Ubuntu 22.04.4 and dual-boot, however, it does not look like my sound card is being recognized. For output I'm only seeing Dummy Output, and no input options. I have tried plugging in my headphones, but those aren't recognized either. I have tried a bunch of recommendations out there while perusing Google but have had no luck. If it helps, I have run this command and here is the output:
sudo lspci -vv | grep -i audio
ubuntu@who-iMacPro:~$ sudo lspci -vv | grep -i audio
02:00.3 Multimedia audio controller: Apple Inc. Apple Audio Device (rev 01)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. Apple Audio Device
f3:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega 10 HDMI Audio [Radeon Vega 56/64]
Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega 10 HDMI Audio [Radeon Vega 56/64]

Alsamixer is also only currently seeing Vega 10 HDMI Audio.
EDIT:
Thank you for the response guiverc, I'll make sure to add more details in the future. I am using the desktop version and here is the output you requested:
ubuntu@who-iMacPro:~$ sudo lshw -C sound

*-multimedia UNCLAIMED    
   description: Multimedia audio controller
   product: Apple Audio Device
   vendor: Apple Inc.
   physical id: 0.3
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.3
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:7f800000-7fbfffff memory:7fd80000-7fdfffff memory:7fe30000-7fe3ffff
*-multimedia
   description: Audio device
   product: Vega 10 HDMI Audio [Radeon Vega 56/64]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:f3:00.1
   logical name: card0
   logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
   logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
   logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D10p
   logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D11p
   logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
   logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
   logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
   logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D9p
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:98 memory:f02a0000-f02a3fff

EDIT2: Adding output for the command Archisman Panigrahi's recommended.
 ubuntu@who-iMacPro:~$ cd snd_hda_macbookpro && sudo ./install.cirrus.driver.sh

 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_jack.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_beep.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_local.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_generic.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/ca0132_regs.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hp_x360_helper.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_beep.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_analog.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_si3054.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_tegra.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_ca0110.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_cs8409-tables.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_controller.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_conexant.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_cs8409.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_eld.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda_i2c.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_ca0132.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_controller.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_cs_dsp_ctl.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_codec.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/thinkpad_helper.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_generic.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_sigmatel.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda_property.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_intel.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_sysfs.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/Kconfig
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_intel_trace.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda_spi.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_intel.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_cirrus.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_hwdep.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_bind.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_jack.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/ideapad_s740_helper.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_hdmi.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_component.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_proc.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_cmedia.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/Makefile
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_via.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_controller_trace.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda_property.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/hda_cs_dsp_ctl.h
 linux-source-6.5.0/sound/pci/hda/patch_cs8409.c
Kernel version later than implemented version - there may be build problems
patching file patch_cs8409.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1445 (offset 175 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 1454 (offset 175 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 1483 (offset 175 lines).
patching file patch_cs8409.h
Hunk #2 succeeded at 304 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 331 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 367 (offset 2 lines).
patching file patch_cirrus_apple.h
make -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-27-generic/build CFLAGS_MODULE="-DAPPLE_PINSENSE_FIXUP -DAPPLE_CODECS -DCONFIG_SND_HDA_RECONFIG=1 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function" M=/home/cd/snd_hda_macbookpro/build/hda modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
You are using:           
CC [M]  /home/cd/snd_hda_macbookpro/build/hda/patch_cs8409.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc-12: not found
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /home/cd snd_hda_macbookpro/build/hda/patch_cs8409.o] Error 127
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27-generic/Makefile:2039: /home/cd/snd_hda_macbookpro/build/hda] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:16: all] Error 2

EDIT 3: Output for commands
ubuntu@who-iMacPro:~/snd-hda-codec-cs8409$ make
make -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-27-generic/build CFLAGS_MODULE="- DAPPLE_PINSENSE_FIXUP -DAPPLE_CODECS -DCONFIG_SND_HDA_RECONFIG=1 -Wno-  unused-variable -Wno-unused-function" M=/home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu   12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
You are using:           
CC [M]  /home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/patch_cs8409.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc-12: not found
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /home/cd/snd-hda-codec-    cs8409/patch_cs8409.o] Error 127
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27-generic/Makefile:2039: /home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:16: all] Error 2
ubuntu@who-iMacPro:~/snd-hda-codec-cs8409$ sudo make install
mkdir -p /lib/modules/6.5.0-27-generic/updates/
cp snd-hda-codec-cs8409.ko /lib/modules/6.5.0-27-generic/updates/
cp: cannot stat 'snd-hda-codec-cs8409.ko': No such file or    directory
make: *** [Makefile:22: install] Error 1

Edit 4: Output after running sudo apt install gcc-12
ubuntu@who-iMacPro:~$ sudo apt install gcc-12
[sudo] password for cd: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cpp-12 libasan8 libgcc-12-dev libtsan2
Suggested packages:
  gcc-12-locales cpp-12-doc gcc-12-multilib gcc-12-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cpp-12 gcc-12 libasan8 libgcc-12-dev libtsan2
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 40.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 138 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 cpp-12 amd64 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 [10.8 MB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libasan8 amd64 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 [2,442 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libtsan2 amd64 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 [2,477 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libgcc-12-dev amd64 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 [2,618 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 gcc-12 amd64 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 [21.7 MB]
Fetched 40.1 MB in 3s (14.8 MB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package cpp-12.
(Reading database ... 241511 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cpp-12_12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpp-12 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libasan8:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libasan8_12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasan8:amd64 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtsan2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libtsan2_12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtsan2:amd64 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgcc-12-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgcc-12-dev_12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc-12-dev:amd64 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-12.
Preparing to unpack .../gcc-12_12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-12 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up cpp-12 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up libasan8:amd64 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up libtsan2:amd64 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up libgcc-12-dev:amd64 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up gcc-12 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
ubuntu@who-iMacPro:~$ cd snd-hda-codec-cs8409
ubuntu@who-iMacPro:~/snd-hda-codec-cs8409$ make
make -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-27-generic/build CFLAGS_MODULE="-DAPPLE_PINSENSE_FIXUP -DAPPLE_CODECS -DCONFIG_SND_HDA_RECONFIG=1 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function" M=/home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  CC [M]  /home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/patch_cs8409.o
In file included from /home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/patch_cs8409.c:1488:
/home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/patch_cirrus_apple.h: In function ‘cs_8409_apple_boot_init’:
/home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/patch_cirrus_apple.h:1191:15: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
 1191 |         hinfo = spec->gen.stream_analog_playback;
      |               ^
  CC [M]  /home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/patch_cs8409-tables.o
  LD [M]  /home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/snd-hda-codec-cs8409.o
  MODPOST /home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/snd-hda-codec-cs8409.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/snd-hda-codec-cs8409.ko
  BTF [M] /home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/snd-hda-codec-cs8409.ko
Skipping BTF generation for /home/cd/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/snd-hda-codec-cs8409.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27-generic'
ubuntu@who-iMacPro:~/snd-hda-codec-cs8409$ sudo make install
mkdir -p /lib/modules/6.5.0-27-generic/updates/
cp snd-hda-codec-cs8409.ko /lib/modules/6.5.0-27-generic/updates/
depmod -a
ubuntu@who-iMacPro:~/snd-hda-codec-cs8409$


Thank you for response guiverc. It looks like Linux sees the audio driver, but it is currently unclaimed. Do you happen to know of any way to claim the driver?

Can you install sudo apt install gcc-12 and then try again?

No dice, added output for the requested command and subsequent compiler code.

Please open an issue here https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro/issues, and add the output of the command sudo ./install.cirrus.driver.sh. I don't think I can help with this anymore.

This answer is based on similar solutions which work in Debian.
First install kernel-headers, and tools for compiling.
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt install build-essential git gcc-12

Download the driver
git clone https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409

Finally, compile and install the driver
cd snd-hda-codec-cs8409
make
sudo make install

Reboot the computer and sound should work.

Thank you for your response Archisman! I ran the commands above but didn't have any luck. I posted the output in the OP. The driver link is different than the git command you posted. I'm not seeing a shell script in the folder I downloaded from the driver link.

@ubuntu_who Can you try the new commands from another repository?

No luck unfortunately. Output posted in the OP

I also had to install git and make packages on a fresh Ubuntu 24.04.1 install.
This works:
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic   
sudo apt install build-essential git gcc-13   
git clone https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409   
cd snd-hda-codec-cs8409  
make  
sudo make install

Reboot and the audio works.
